# Can git Add Commit Comments to End of File Like CVS

Tags: git

I remember from a long time ago when I used CVS that when I updated a file the comments from the commit would appear at the end of the file.  Is there a way to get git to add those comments to files?  It was sort of a change log at the end of the file and it was really helpful.

The comments would look like this:

```
# Revision 1.2  2007/09/18 19:11:14  joeuser
# BugId:8205
# Reviewer(s):joeuser
# Description: Latest version.
```

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: You could try to use a post commit hook to paste the changes while checking the working tree out.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want your source control bleeding into your content? You understand that this is very contrary to the idea of git. Or how do you intend to represent merges with that format. Or rebases?

Comment: I solved this issue, after a lot of reading on this topic and some time, with pre-commit.  I intercept the files that are being modified, check a config file to see if they are being updated with per file versioning and logs, update the files, and the add them back before they are commited.